# Building problems in Fortran: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: fortran, geany

I have following problem:

I am using Geany as a IDE for Fortran programming, and can not set it up to build my programs, in which I am using functions or subroutine as external files.

After building function or subroutine I get following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And after building the main program I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fibsub_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccQa02jI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, now I am building all my programs using terminal commands in a shell script. With the shell script everything works fine and it looks like this:

```
cd Desktop/Fortran
rm -f *.o
rm -f exe
gfortran -c  sub.f90 main.f90
gfortran -o exe sub.o main.o
./exe
```

My main question is: how to make it all work in Geany? It looks like it is not possible to build those files separately, and it works only if you build them all together in one line.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How do you configure Geany to build your program ? As far as I remember, only "make" is provided by default, which assumes that a makefile exists somewhere...

Comment: I don't really configure anything, because I have know idea what to configure, I've just tried to give the right path to the builder, so it knows in what folder all the files are. But it haven't worked...

Comment: Geany knows almost nothing about Fortran. So it is probable that its build command tries to compile file by alphabetic order. But this is NOT the way Fortran expects. So it is better to write your own Makefile.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try to write a Makefile. So, do you think the problem is the way how Geany tries to compile those files? I mean: to build the program properly, I need to build all the files at the same time, as I do in a shell file, but when Geany builds it, it tries to build it one after another... Could this be the problem?